# I want to split by either word "full" or "incr" or "manual" whichever is in current line

Tags: powershell, split

I have line as shown below

```
rspedw03.corpads.local 3085876532 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 incr 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/29/2022  disk 1645592426 backup 3013 MB JCBDD2301P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2 JC_DB Clone_DR    full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 04/04/2022         disk 1645592431 Clone_DR    997 KB MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2                   full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 03/30/2022         disk 1645592431             997 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
rsuedw03.corpads.local 12608 MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days MN_DB Clone_DR full 02/23/2022 04/21/2022 04/21/2022      disk 1645592432 Clone_DR     13 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
```

I want to split by either word "full" or "incr" or "manual" whichever is in current line. Basically i want 2nd date from below lines

```
rspedw02.corpads.local 4829860108 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 incr 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/26/2022  disk 1645592421 Clone_DR 4716 MB MNBDD5304P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rspedw02.corpads.local 4829860108 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 incr 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/28/2022  disk 1645592421 backup 4716 MB JCBDD2301P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rspedw03.corpads.local 3085876532 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 full 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/22/2022  disk 1645592426 Clone_DR 3013 MB MNBDD5304P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rspedw03.corpads.local 3085876532 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 manual 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/29/2022  disk 1645592426 backup 3013 MB JCBDD2301P.CORPADS.LOCAL
```

Comment: and `-split 'full|incr|manual' ` does not work?  ... and if you only want to split on separater words you can do `  -split '\sfull\s|\sincr\s|\smanual\s'  `

Comment: $line.split 'incr'|'full'|'manual' does not work

Comment: Think you're referring to the .Net method which is literal. You want `-Spit` which takes *RegEx* input as @
Olaf suggested.

Comment: $line.spit 'incr'|'full'|'manual'  did not work either. I am using powershell

Comment: You are using the .NET method `split()`, which does not use regular expressions. Try the PowerShell `-Split` operator, which does - instead of `$line.split(...)`, use `$line -split "incr|full|manual"`.

Comment: I also recommend that you find a good book or three on PowerShell and read through it and understand how it works. The "...Month of Lunches" series of books from Manning Publications is generally written accessibly, as is the unfortunately-named "...for Dummies" series of books from John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Jeff , how do make incr case sensitive so only look for all lower case ?

Comment: I am looking for 2nd date from below lines , hw do i get that ?

Comment: if you're looking for case sensitive matches, use the case sensitive operator for `-split`: `-csplit`.

Comment: I commend to your attention the [Microsoft Docs site, specifically the page on about_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split)

Comment: It did help , one more help i am looking for if statement to work with date , if date is <= to 365 then process , $newdate=[Datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
              if ( ($today - $newdate) -lt 400 )

Comment: @postmaster420, as for your follow-up question: please crate a _new_ question post (though I suspect you will find existing answers here to help you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex. This regex might or might not be stringent enough, but this is a start. It assumes a specific date format which is not optimal.

```
Get-Content -Path .\spl.txt |
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '.*( full | incr | manual )[\d/]{10} ([\d/]{10}).*') {
            $Matches[2]
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i want to grab group names which are between number and before backup type (incr,full or manual)  in each lines. Group can be one, two or three or more. Then i want put them in hash table corresponding to that server which is first entry in each line. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The second date after the word of interest is the second whitespace-separated token; instead of a [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) approach, which would require multiple steps, you can use a single [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation to extract it:

```sh
# Sample array of input lines.
$lines = @'
rspedw03.corpads.local 3085876532 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 incr 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/29/2022  disk 1645592426 backup 3013 MB JCBDD2301P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2 JC_DB Clone_DR    full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 04/04/2022         disk 1645592431 Clone_DR    997 KB MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2                   full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 03/30/2022         disk 1645592431             997 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
rsuedw03.corpads.local 12608 MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days MN_DB Clone_DR full 02/23/2022 04/21/2022 04/21/2022      disk 1645592432 Clone_DR     13 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Replace $lines with (Get-Content $yourFile) to read from a file
$lines -creplace '^.+ (?:full|incr|manual) .+? (.+?) .*', '$1'
```

Note the use of `-creplace`, the case-*sensitive* variant of the `-replace` operator.

For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/w33DWn/2).

Output:

```sh
03/29/2022
04/04/2022
04/04/2022
04/21/2022
```